# Druid segments not available from some moment

Tags: druid

Ingestion task was success but segments are unavailable from some moment. 
I can't restart master node.. because it is not personal server. 
Why segments are unavailable? or How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to some reasons, it has segments in meta-data database, and tries to download them, but it cannot. Either your historical node's disk is full, or there are some connection issues for it to download the segments from your deep storage (if it is S3 for example, but if your deep storage is a local disk or a mounted network drive, see why it cannot access them).

Segments are available only if historical BE ABLE to download them; historical nodes are instructed by coordinator to download segments.

It may be in process of downloading them and no specific error has occurred, but the performance is poor and it takes time for it to download all of them and make them available

Maybe it cannot (read historical log)

Maybe coordinator has some issues (read coordinator log)

In any case, if a segment is available, the log entries for those possible errors can be either found in historical's log or coordinator's log.